# casperjs testing an internal site

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to run a casper test for an internal site. Its running on pre-production environment, the code so far is

```
    var casper = require('casper').create({
                 verbose: true,
                 loglevel:"debug"
                 });

    // listening to a custom event
    casper.on('page.loaded', function() {
              this.echo('The page title is ' + this.getTitle());
              this.echo('value is: '+ this.getElementAttribute
                       ('input[id="edit-capture-amount"]', 
                        'value'));
    });

    casper.start('https://preprod.uk.systemtest.com', function() {
                 this.echo(this.getTitle());
                 this.capture('frontpage.png');
                 // emitting a custom event
                 this.emit('age.loaded.loaded');    
    });

    casper.run();
```

as you can see its not much but my problem is the address is not reachable. The capture also shows a blank page. Not sure what i am doing wrong. I have checked the code with cnn and google urls, the title and screen capture works fine. Not sure how to make it work for an internal site.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. In my browser I could resolve the url, but capserjs could not. All I got was `about::blank` for a web page.

**Adding the `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` worked like a charm!**

```
casperjs mytestjs //didn't work

capserjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes mytestjs //worked perfect!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure.

Can you reach preprod.uk.systemtest.com from the computer on which casper runs ? For example with a ping or wget.

Is there any proxy between your computer and the preprod server ? Or is your system configured to pass through a proxy that should not be used for the preprod server ?

The casper code seems to be ok.

*I know this should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.*

Comment: preprod is pretty locked up and the only machine which has permission to that server is a workstation which is running this test. the machine is inside the same network and hence there isn't any proxy.

i am not sure if casper uses a different ip address to reach the web address because if it does that address needs to be white listed in the ngnix server too

Comment: If the workstation is on the same network as the preprod server it should be easy to guess what is its IP address. Consider Casper simply as a normal web browser. Can you reach the page with wget ?

Comment: it does say it can connect from wget i am pasting in the output

Comment: C:\dev> wget.exe https://preprod.uk.systemtest.com/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2013-03-06 17:18:58--  https://preprod.uk.systemtest.com/
Resolving preprod.uk.systemtest.com... 100.300.30.210
Connecting to preprod.uk.systemtest.com|100.300.30.210|:4403... connected.

Comment: ERROR: cannot verify preprod.uk.systemtest.com's certificate, issued by `/C=UK/ST=London/L=London/O=system':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
ERROR: certificate common name `' doesn't match requested host name `preprod.uk.systemtest.com'.
To connect to preprod.uk.systemtest.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: i was considering Casper a simple browser but all this seems like its going in from another ip. I might be wrong but seems like it. If  i run the same test on RC it works fine.

Comment: and to avoid the ssl error i was using --ignore-ssl-errors=yes

Answer (score 0):

As far as CasperJs tests are run in localhost, for testing a custom domain/subdomain/host, some headers need to be defined.

I experienced some problems when passing only the HOST header, for instance, snapshots were not taken properly.

I added 2 more headers and now my tests run properly:

```
    casper.on('started', function () {
        var testHost = 'preprod.uk.systemtest.com';

        this.page.customHeaders = {
            'HOST': testHost,
            'HTTP_HOST': testHost,
            'SERVER_NAME': testHost
        };
    });

    var testing_url: 'http://localhost:8000/app_test.php';
    casper.start(_testing_url, function() {
    this.echo('I am using symfony, so this should have to show the homepage for the domain: preprod.uk.systemtest.com');
    this.echo('An the snapshot is also working');
    this.capture('casper_capture.png');
}
```